# Calling a rest api from Oracle PLSQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am calling a get method of a REST api from oracle. This service must be called when a new record is inserted into a given table. For this I have created a trigger that executes a stored procedure that calls the service. This service must read the row that was just inserted and do something with it. The issue is that when I insert the row the service is called but it does nothing. When I insert a second row, the service runs and then it processes the first, not the second row.

This is the trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER MYUSER."my_trigger" AFTER INSERT ON "MYUSER"."INCOMING_DATA" REFERENCING OLD AS "OLD" NEW AS "NEW"
BEGIN
external_services_proc;
END;
```

This is the SP:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MYUSER.external_services_proc
AS
response CLOB;
BEGIN
        select utl_http.request('http://localhost:8080/api/inData') into response from dual;

END external_services_proc;
```

I want to clarify that if I disable the trigger and insert the row, and then execute the SP, everything works ok and the service reads and processes the row. I think the problem is in the dynamics of the trigger itself, I think.

Any idea?

Comment: are you sure the procedure "external_services_proc" sees the data that is inserted ? I would think you have to pass the new values as argument to that procedure.

Comment: yes, if i call de sp from a query or execute this manually, its works. The function of the sp is only to call de rest api service. It´s not work when it's call from the trigger.

Comment: I think that is because the row does not exist yet when the trigger is executed. Pass the column values as arguments